# index a list of lists in one loop

Tags: python, loops

What logic can I use a single index to iterate through two lists in one loop, e.g, using indexes `[0,0]`, `[0,1]`, `[1,0]`, `[1,1]` for a 2x2 iterating through `1` `2` `3` `4`? Here is my best attempt so far:

```
numbers_list = [[1,2],[3,4]]
letters_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for i in [1,2,3,4]:
    indx1, = i%2,
    indx2 = i % 2 + i-2
    print indx1, indx2
    print numbers_list[indx1][indx2], letters_list[i]
```

desired output is

```
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
```

Comment: I don't understand, why don't you just loop over the lists? *Why on earth would you want to do it this way?*

Comment: Using a single loop, you want to show both `numbers_list` and `letters_list` ? Am I getting that correctly?

Comment: what should the output look like?

Comment: And the lists are always of the same order? As in one being a 2D list and another a 1D list?

Comment: KaushikNP - yes.

Comment: Indexed *what way?* Can you describe the *actual problem you are trying to solve*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't know the `generic structure` of your lists, am gonna take the `lists` you provided. So in a `single loop` :

```
for i in range(4): 
   div,rem = divmod(i,2) 
   print(numbers_list[div][rem],letters_list[i])
```

So, we get :

```
IN : letters_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
IN : numbers_list = [[1,2],[3,4]]

OUT : 1 a
      2 b
      3 c
      4 d
```

Answer (score 1):

Just nest the loops.

```
lists = [[1,2],[3,4]]
for i in range(len(lists)):
    sublist = lists[i]
    for j in range(len(sublist)):
        element = sublist[j]
        print element
```

This will give:
1
2
3
4

Your method will work, but you have to know the length of the lists. Also all your lists have to be the same length, whereas with this method they can vary.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not opposed to using a built-in function like [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) this may work:

```
numbers_list = [[1,2],[3,4]]
letters_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for i, n in enumerate([1,2,3,4]):
    print i, letters_list[i]
```

output:

```
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.product`.

For a 2x3 list:

```
from itertools import product

numbers_list = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]

for i, j in itertools.product(range(2), range(3)):
    print("indices:")
    print(i)
    print(j)
    print("Item:")
    print(numbers_list[i][j])
```

If you just want to flatten the list into a list of tuples containing (index_1, index_2, item), you could do a nested list comprehension:

```
letter_list = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]
[(i, j, x) for i, y in enumerate(letter_list) for j, x in enumerate(y)]

#Returns [(0, 0, 'A'), (0, 1, 'B'), (0, 2, 'C'), (1, 0, 'D'), (1, 1, 'E'), (1, 2, 'F')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to handle any shape of two-deep nested lists in a single top-level loop, you could first define a helper iterator function (you only need to do this once):

```
def nest_iter(x):
    for i, a in enumerate(x):
        for j, b in enumerate(a):
            yield i, j, b
```

Once you have that, you can use it in the rest of your code as follows:

```
numbers_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]

for i, j, b in nest_iter(numbers_list):
    print i, j, b
```

The output is:

```
0 0 1
0 1 2
1 0 3
1 1 4
1 2 5
```

In this example, there are two sub-lists of different lengths.